# Using awk to extract specific line from all text files in a directory

Tags: bash, awk

I have a folder with 50 text files and I want to extract the first line from each of them at the command line and output this to a result.txt file.

I'm using the following command within the directory that contains the files I'm working with:

```
for files in *; do awk '{if(NR==1) print NR, $0}' *.txt; done > result.txt
```

When I run the command, the result.txt file contains 50 lines but they're all from a single file in the directory rather than one line per file. The common appears to be looping over a single 50 times rather than over each of the 50 files.

I'd be grateful if someone could help me understand where I'm going wrong with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use head? For example with find:

```
find midir/ -type f -exec head -1 {} \; >> result.txt
```

If you want to follow your approach you need to specify the file and not use the wildcard with awk:

```
for files in *; do awk '{if(NR==1) print NR, $0}' "$files"; done > result.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

try this -

```
for i in *.txt;do head -1 $i;done > result.txt
```

OR

```
for files in *.txt;do awk 'NR==1 {print $0}'  $i;done > result.txt
```

Comment: Excellent, many thanks to you both. Both of these solutions work a treat

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two problems:

1. You have an outer loop that iterates over `*`, but your loop body doesn't use `$files`. That is, you're invoking `awk '...' *.txt` 50 times. This is why any output from awk is repeated 50 times in `result.txt`.
2. Your awk code checks `NR` (the number of lines read so far), not `FNR` (the number of lines read *within the current file*). `NR==1` is true only at the beginning of the very first file.

There's another problem: `result.txt` is created first, so it is included among `*.txt`. To avoid this, give it a different name (one that doesn't end in `.txt`) or put it in a different directory.

A possible fix:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {print NR, $0}' *.txt > result
```